# Var delete or not delete?

Tags: angularjs, jslint

When my code like this

```
var app = angular.module('PhotoViewer', []);
var photos = [
```

i have error: combine this with previous 'var' statement.
When it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('PhotoViewer', []);
photos = [
```

i have error: 'photos' was used before defined;
What I must to do?

Comment: Replace the `;` with a `,`. But I would turn that linting option off. It's much clearer if every variable is declared with its own var keyword.

Comment: Might you consider using `let` more often? It's the future of non-hoisted goodness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the `var` using a comma , if you want to declare in single `var`

```
var app = angular.module('PhotoViewer', []),
photos = [];
```

This also works,

```
var photos = [];
var app = angular.module('PhotoViewer', []);
```

Answer (score -1):

The probleem is that you don't close the array brackets.

Comment: That's not _the_ problem. It's _a_ problem, but they just didn't paste the code properly.